# How do I write 'WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE' in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, db2

In DB2, I can Write

```
 MERGE INTO    Table1 AS A
       USING (
       SELECT *
   FROM        TABLE2
   WHERE        NO.1 = NO.2) AS B ON
   A.TOKEN_ID = B.TOKEN_ID
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET        A.LINK_POSTING_IND = 1;
```

But MYSQL doesn't support MERGE, So how could I re-write this code in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may rephrase your merge statement in MySQL using an update join:

```
UPDATE Table1 A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOKEN_ID
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE NO.1 = NO.2
) B
    ON A.TOKEN_ID = B.TOKEN_ID
SET
    LINK_POSTING_IND = 1;
```